# Reading from drive using int 13h with bootloader on real machine

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

Hey I'm trying to load up a string that I have placed at the end of my bootloader, or at 0x7e00. I'm trying to use int 13h to load the string into memory and then print it to the screen. I check for errors, but no errors occur. However, nothing gets printed to the screen, it just hangs with a blank screen.

Here is my bootloader code:

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]

mov byte [driveno], dl    ;save dl

;set up stack
xor ax, ax
cli
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x9000
sti

;set up segment regs
jmp 0x0000:start
start:
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

;reset drive
xor ax, ax
int 0x13

;read 2nd sector
mov al, 0x01
mov bx, 0
mov es, bx
mov bx, 0x7e00
mov cx, 0x0002
xor dh, dh
mov dl, byte [driveno]
mov ah, 0x02
int 0x13

jc read_error   ;Apparently no error!!!

mov ah, 0x01   ;Check status of last operation
int 0x13

mov dx, ax     ;Print the value stored in ax
call printhex   ;This outputs 0x0001 or al=01 so I get an invalid function error?

mov si, 0x7e00   ;print my "loaded" message
call print

mov si, teststr  ;test if my print function works, it does.
call print

cli
hlt
jmp $

read_error:
mov si, error
call print
ret

print:
loop:
lodsb
or al, al
jz done
mov ah, 0x0e
mov bx, 0x0003 ;page 0 and default color
int 0x10
jmp loop
done:
ret

printhex:   ;This method allows me to see what is inside of registers such    as ax.
push bx
push si
mov si, hex_template

mov bx, dx
shr bx, 12
mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
mov [hex_template+2], bl

mov bx, dx
shr bx, 8
and bx, 0x000f
mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
mov [hex_template+3], bl

mov bx, dx
shr bx, 4
and bx, 0x000f
mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
mov [hex_template+4], bl

mov bx, dx
and bx, 0x000f
mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
mov [hex_template+5], bl

call print
pop si
pop bx
ret


error db 'Error',0
teststr db 'Printing works',0

hex_template db '0x????',0  ;For my hex print method
hexabet db '0123456789abcdef' ;Also for my hex print method

driveno db 0      ;Storing dl

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

db 'ABCD',0   ;this needs to be loaded

times 1024-($-$$) db 0   ;fill my file so it is 2 whole sectors
```

I compile with

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
```

and i write to my usb using

```
dd if=boot.bin of=\\.\e: bs=512 count=2
```

does anyone know why my message doesn't get displayed when I boot to my usb?
thanks!

Comment: Looks correct on first glance. Try not to reload `dl`, it's set to the boot drive by the BIOS - maybe it uses floppy emulation and then it's not going to be `0x80`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yeah I have even tried saving `dl` into memory and reloading it later, still doesn't work... it's weird because everything online says it should work too

Comment: For the record, it works fine in `qemu`. Also, do not set `sp` to `0xffff` because it's a bad idea to use odd (unaligned) addresses. I doubt that has anything to do with your problem, however,

Comment: It must have something to do with my BIOS then... maybe qemu is setting some things up that I'm not in my code

Comment: Furthermore check that your `dd` writes out partial blocks - even better, pad your second block to a full sector too, such as by adding `times 1024-($-$$) db 0`.

Comment: Hmm.. that still didn't seem to solve it. I also tried booting it on another device also to confirm it wasn't just my pc. Again, it loads a blank screen on my other pc as well.

Comment: Does it work if you print something from the same boot sector that's already loaded?

Comment: Yep, if I manually force it to print the error message to the screen it is able to do that.

Comment: Checked on my laptop, works fine.

Comment: Interesting! So it has to be my bios then. I'm booting off of a USB, so it must be using some sort of emulation. Maybe I have a buggy BIOS? Would there be any sort of special code I would need to include to work around this? I have an Insyde F. 42 BIOS.

Comment: You tried on two machines, hopefully not the same bios ... have you tried different usb device? Have you tried dd back to a file and verify you got the second sector actually on the medium? Also make sure your OS is not fooling around with the disk.

Comment: Yep I can successfully run it off of a test.bin that I read from my usb using dd. And the BIOS's are different.

Comment: Post your updated version where you save and restore DL so were all on the same page. Ralf Brown's Interrupt List mentions that INT 10h AH=0Eh takes BL, BH parameters (colour, page number) though VirtualBox's BIOS appears to ignore them. Maybe your's isn't. The RBIL also says that INT 13h AH=01 returns the status in AH not AL.

Comment: Okay turns out my BIOS puts the status into AL, I output the whole AX register anyway. I don't get a cannot find address mark error anymore, it is simply a 01h or Invalid Function error.

Comment: Your code assumes DS = 0 when it saves DL, try moving that line to after you initialize the segment registers.

Comment: Still didn't seem to fix anything... it still outputs an invalid function error

Comment: Try using the [extended read function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D42h:_Extended_Read_Sectors_From_Drive).

Comment: I have tried but I read somewhere that my bios doesn't support it

Answer (score 0):

You should rearrange your code like this.

```
    [org 0x7c00]
    [bits 16]
    jmp 0x00:0x7c00
start:  
    ;set up stack and segment registers
    xor ax, ax
    cli
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x9000
    sti
    ;Save driveno
    mov byte[driveno],dl
    ;reset drive
    xor ax, ax
    int 0x13

    ;read 2nd sector
    mov al, 0x01
    mov bx, 0
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0x7e00
    mov cx, 0x0002
    xor dh, dh
    mov dl, byte [driveno]
    mov ah, 0x02
    int 0x13

    jc read_error   ;Apparently no error!!!

    mov ah, 0x01   ;Check status of last operation
    int 0x13

    mov dx, ax     ;Print the value stored in ax
    call printhex   ;This outputs 0x0001 or al=01 so I get an invalid function error?

    mov si, 0x7e00   ;print my "loaded" message
    call print

    mov si, teststr  ;test if my print function works, it does.
    call print

    cli
    hlt
    jmp $

    read_error:
    mov si, error
    call print
    ret

    print:
    loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz done
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov bx, 0x0003 ;page 0 and default color
    int 0x10
    jmp loop
    done:
    ret

    printhex:   ;This method allows me to see what is inside of registers such    as ax.
    push bx
    push si
    mov si, hex_template

    mov bx, dx
    shr bx, 12
    mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
    mov [hex_template+2], bl

    mov bx, dx
    shr bx, 8
    and bx, 0x000f
    mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
    mov [hex_template+3], bl

    mov bx, dx
    shr bx, 4
    and bx, 0x000f
    mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
    mov [hex_template+4], bl

    mov bx, dx
    and bx, 0x000f
    mov bx, [bx+hexabet]
    mov [hex_template+5], bl

    call print
    pop si
    pop bx
    ret


    error db 'Error',0
    teststr db 'Printing works',0

    hex_template db '0x????',0  ;For my hex print method
    hexabet db '0123456789abcdef' ;Also for my hex print method

    driveno db 0      ;Storing dl

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55

    db 'ABCD',0   ;this needs to be loaded

    times 1024-($-$$) db 0   ;fill my file so it is 2 whole sectors
```

It should have solved your problem.

Comment: It's pretty early here but I think you just posted broken code.  The BIOS will load this bootsector at either 7c00:0000 or at 0000:7c00 (which are equivalent in real mode).  You then immediately perform `jmp 0x00:0x7c00` which will stop everything in its tracks and enter an infinite loop.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I think you mean `07C0:0000` and `0000:7C00` are equivalent. Only two things you should assume. Your code will start executing at physical address `0x00007c00` and that _DL_ has the drive letter. You can't assume what segment is in _CS_. Although a segment of `0x07C0` and `0000` are common nothing prevents a BIOS jumping to an off ball location like `0x2030:5BD0` which also maps to physical address `0x00007c00`. (2030<<4+5BD0)

Comment: Whoops!  Yes, I sure did.